# cannot find -lboost_program_options

Tags: c, boost, compiler-construction, mingw, flann

I got some error when I compile flann in windows. I install the boost and gcc 4.3.3. Where is this error come from and how can I solve that?

```
g++ src/*.o  -o cbir -lboost_program_options -lhdf5 -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -llog4cxx -lflann
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_program_options collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:29: recipe for target `cbir' failed
make: *** [cbir] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

boost_program_options needs to be compiled. Check out that you habe the precompiled lib avalable for your compiler. And that you set the corresponding path in your make file, e.g. 
In Qt .pro files:

```
    LIBS += -L"c:/pathToLib"
```

Comment: I compiled my boost and I have several version of boost_program_options but 1- I'm not sure did in right way (boost a little tricky) 2- Where can I put that! I'm so sorry all these because I'm new in programming as u sure find out before then plz guid me in e simplest way! :P

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/g-how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path to see how to set the path to the library...