# gcc and g++ library search paths

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I had all my code compiling under a system that had gcc 4.1.1 and g++ 4.1.1. IT just gave me another system , that had gcc 4.1.2 and g++ 4.1.2.  When I run with -v option, it says

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/x86_64-redhat-linux"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
```

However find gives me this

```
find /usr -name stddef.h
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.1/include/stddef.h
```

How do I force gcc to use a different search paths for i386 and 4.1.1, rather than 4.1.2 and x86_64 ?

Comment: Is g++ failing to compile trivial programs? Then call IT and get them to fix it instead of using fragile workarounds (`-isystem` if you must).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there were 64 bit libraries mixed with 32 libs, on a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would indicate that the installation of gcc isn't complete. You may need to install (e.g. `sudo yum install libstdc++-devel glibc-devel`). This will work assuming that the `gcc` was actually installed using the standard packages from redhat. You may of course need some other libraries too, depending on what you are actually developing.

Of course, the RIGHT thing to do is to complain to IT, but I suspect that if you want some work done today (if your IT is anything like the ones I've worked with), you're better off doing it yourself, if you at all can do that. (Oh, and most of the time, in my experience, they have no idea how to solve the problem, so give them the above information!).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there were 64 bit libraries mixed with 32 libs, on a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend searched with `-I` for includes and `-L` for libs parameter followed by desired paths. See more in the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727033/1387612)