Dyamically load platform specific dlls e.g. MicroSoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Created a class library that is running SQL query using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.
Used DLL of that class library in console app (Including MIcrosoft.Data.SQLClient.dll)
When running method of class library getting above error
If referring MIcrosoft.Data.SQLClient.dll from runtimes\win\lib\net6.0
error got changed to (DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll)
And if trying to add reference of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll giving Bad IL format issue

Working Solution

If switching AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.UseManagedNetworkingOnWindows", true); Setting this at starting working fine but this is not  recommended to use by Microsoft

If referring  MIcrosoft.Data.SQLClient.dll from runtimes\unix\lib\net6.0 it also works fine Don't know why but it doesn't seems good solution and can't use.

If installing the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in console app (Can't update existing Component handler)


Platform (VS 2022 and Win 10 .Net 6)

You do not have SQL Server installed on the machine so you need to download the SQLClient : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/download-microsoft-sqlclient-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver16  If it is already loaded than something is wrong on you linux machine with the library path.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path

Thanks @jdweng working on windows and it is working with above solution but can't use any one of above

What type of machine?  x86 or x64?  See https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/727 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#unable-to-load-native-sni-server-name-indication-library  Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/k7137bfe(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I think SNI files are not being included and when going to reference them throwing BAD IL format may because of they are written in C++. Lots of related issue found on various forum but  all have only solutions already mentioned above which we can't use

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/k7137bfe(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks

I tried it to build with any CPU and even 86 ,64 but same issue @jdweng sorry don't have much knowledge on this is there a solution for this

If you can clarify in the question: (1) What platform are you developing on and (2) What platform (is it a container/docker?) are you deploying to because this feels like a problem where what you are building is for a different platform to what you are deploying to.

Concerning your "step (2) Used DLL of that class library." You can't just use a dll because the dependencies may not be handled correctly. You must either have a project reference to it or a package reference. How are you referencing it?

@ChrisFCarroll  we have existing Component manager (Window Service) developed using .Net 6 for which  we can create component  we have already few of component handled by it
same thing was working in .net 4.X we have upgraded it to .Net 6 (Manager and component both are updated to .Net 6)
after updating to .Net 6 we start getting this error

@ChrisFCarroll we are creating package of component and loading DLL in component manager created similar application for cloning this issue  where instead of loading DLL dynamically used them as project reference. Issue is similar to https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/727

So someone in your organisation has written code to dynamically load packages? (a nupkg or just a directory of dlls or something?)

there is code to dynamically load dll. Instead of using that code if adding reference of DLL getting same issue so I don't think this is an issue  with that code

I think this is harder on .Net than it was in NetFramework. See for instance https://github.com/natemcmaster/DotNetCorePlugins , which is not a small amount of code. For most of us, msbuild handles tricky platform-specific cases both for Project references and for Package references, but if you load DLLs dynamically in Net6 then it looks like you need a lot more code to do it.

You can't just “use” a dll, there's some work involved in loading the assembly, especially when it has platform-specific transitive dependencies.
This area of .Net is different under NetCore compared to NetFramework, so code that worked for NetFramework doesn't work for NetCore.

For .Net Framework, the discussion at Best Practices for Assembly Loading works.

For .Net Core, the discussion at Dependency Loading helps but a faster start might be working through Nate McMaster's Plugin code


